# Sinch, Parse: How to send pictures with my chat app using Parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform, sinch

I'm working on an instant messaging app with **Sinch** and **Parse** integrated in it. 
I wanted to ask if I can add function to **send pictures** using these two services. And if not with these two, than is there any other way, maybe any other service which can combine with Sinch and Parse and let me send pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinch is not supporting any attachments at the moment.
that a shame cause their Video service(beta) is great.
I can recommend you to use [Layer](https://developer.layer.com/docs/android/integration#sending) which support sending images.
We had some issues with the integration at first (iOS and Android as well)
but after all is setup, it works great.

Comment: I can't find any tutorial for layer + parse. Can you please suggest me any good? I'm building for Android BTW.

Comment: Might be worth trying ChatSDK: http://www.binpress.com/app/chat-messaging-sdk-for-android/2326 which supports image messages